# How to solve a FolderClosedIOException?

Tags: apache, email, exception, io, directory

So I am new to Apache Camel. I know that most of this code is probably not the most efficient way to do this, but I have made a code that uses Apache Camel to access my gmail, grab the new messages and if they have attachments save the attachments in a specified directory. My route saves the body data as a file in that directory. Everytime the DataHandler tries to use the getContent() method, whether its saving a file or trying to print the body to System.out, I get either a FolderClosedIOException or a FolderClosed Exception. I have not clue how to fix it. The catch reopens the folder but it just closes again after getting another message.

```
import org.apache.camel.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import com.sun.mail.util.FolderClosedIOException;

public class Imap {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("imaps://imap.gmail.com?username=********@gmail.com&password=******"
                    + "&debugMode=false&closeFolder=false&mapMailMessage=false"
                    + "&connectionTimeout=0").to("file:\\EMAIL");
            }
        });

        Map<String,String> props = new HashMap<String,String>();
        props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.imap.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.imap.host","imap.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

        context.setProperties(props);
        Folder inbox = null;
        ConsumerTemplate template = context.createConsumerTemplate();
        context.start();

        while(true) {
            try {
                Exchange e = template.receive("imaps://imap.gmail.com?username=*********@gmail.com&password=***********", 60000);
                if(e == null) break;

                Message m = e.getIn();

                Map<String, Object> s = m.getHeaders();
                Iterator it = s.entrySet().iterator();
                while(it.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                    System.out.println(pairs.getKey()+" === "+pairs.getValue()+"\n\n");
                    it.remove();
                } 
                if(m.hasAttachments()) {
                    Map<String,DataHandler> att = m.getAttachments();
                    for(String s1 : att.keySet()) {
                        DataHandler dh = att.get(s1);
                        String filename = dh.getName();
                        ByteArrayOutputStream o = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        dh.writeTo(o);
                        byte[] by = o.toByteArray();
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:/EMAIL/"+filename);
                        out.write(by);
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();


                    }
                }

            } catch(FolderClosedIOException ex) {
                inbox = ex.getFolder();
                inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            }
        }

        context.stop();




    }
```

}

Please somebody tell me whats wrong!!

The error occurs here:

```
dh.writeTo(o);
```

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution for this? I am working on exact same issue and getting the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

We were was solving a similar problem in akka-camel

The solution i believe was to use manual acknowledgement and send an acknowledgement after we were done with the message.